# How to decide maximum input current required in linear charging method?

Tags: current, charging, input, linear

I am using MCP73213 IC for my charging application. I would like to use the maximum capacity of the IC for charging. i.e., 1 ampere charge current during constant current charge cycle.And input voltage is 9 volts. What the maximum input current required for this application. I want to use 9 volt adapter as input. Please help me in this regard.

Reference schematic is seen from the datasheet linked below.
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20002190C.pdf

Thankyou.

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing the voltage it's delivering that 1 Amp charging current at and seeing the schematic. Please edit your question to add in the necessary details.

Comment: The MCP73213 is a linear regulator, so if you want 1A output you have to have 1A input.

Comment: My input voltage is 9 volts.

Comment: (1) That information was already in your question. Finbarr said you need to give us "the voltage *it's delivering at* - not the voltage it's being supplied with. Put it in your question - not in the comments. (2) Do you understand Steve G's comment?